# java.lang.NullPointerException after reading file as InputStream from AssetManager

Tags: android

AssetManager defination and use:

```
...
AssetManager mngr = getAssets();
try{
      encrypter.decrypt(mngr.open("sample.txt"),output_file);
}...(continued)
```

decrypt function:

```
public void decrypt(InputStream in, OutputStream out)
    {
            try
            {
                    // Bytes read from in will be decrypted
                    in = new CipherInputStream(in, dcipher);
                    // Read in the decrypted bytes and write the cleartext to out
                    int numRead = 0;
                    while ((numRead = in.read(buf)) >= 0)
                    {
                      out.write(buf, 0, numRead);
                    }
                    out.close();
            ...(continued)
```

Its giving error for line **out.write(buf, 0, numRead);** as java.lang.NullPointerException.

This call was working fine when used as:

*encrypter.decrypt(new FileInputStream("sample.txt"),output_file)* (i.e. when reading file from local than assets directory of android);

Any reasons why?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: show full code, i mean declaration

Comment: declaration of which part.. AssetManager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your OutputStream is not initialized.So you are getting null pointer exception.you may want
something like this

```
 public void decrypt(InputStream in,String file)
        {
                try
                {
                 OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        // Bytes read from in will be decrypted
                        in = new CipherInputStream(in, dcipher);
                        // Read in the decrypted bytes and write the cleartext to out
                        int numRead = 0;
                        while ((numRead = in.read(buf)) >= 0)
                        {
                          out.write(buf, 0, numRead);
                        }
                        out.close();
```

Comment: Thanks the problem was exactly what you said.. Thank a lot.